# how to style two nested elements with the same parent

Tags: html, css

I have a quiz to change styling for two (p) inside (div) elements but the first one the border color is `#ff5622`, and the second has a different color like this image How to do that [image]

```
<div>
 <p>This Is Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a clear and detailed description of your problem, with all code needed to reproduce it. "Change styling" is very vague - I have no idea what you actually need to be able to do here, nor how you want to do it. Inline styles? Stylesheet? Specific selectors? Classes/IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector.

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
> child, regardless of type, of its parent.
>
> n can be a number, a keyword, or a formula.
>
> Tip: Look at the :nth-of-type() selector to select the element that is
> the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Or the [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) property.

If your HTML is :

```css
div:nth-of-type(1) > p {
  color: red;
}


div:nth-of-type(2) > p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how to do it inside the first div and the second div

Comment: @RagaeyM.Ragaa Check my answer, does it answers your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can give class for every "p" tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <style>
  .p1{
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.p2{
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  }
 </style>
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <p class="p1">This is paragraph</p>
  <p class="p2">This is paragraph</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: haaa no he won't change the code or give a class or identifier to HTML code he wants to change the code in CSS without using any class or ids

Comment: Then you should use DOM manipulation to do that.